# Reverse Pagination Through A Redis Sorted Set

Tags: pagination, redis, sortedset

Consider a Redis sorted set with the following members:

```
ZADD mySortedSet 11 "A"
ZADD mySortedSet 21 "B"
ZADD mySortedSet 32 "C"
ZADD mySortedSet 46 "D"
ZADD mySortedSet 53 "E"
ZADD mySortedSet 68 "F"
ZADD mySortedSet 72 "G"
ZADD mySortedSet 82 "H" 
ZADD mySortedSet 94 "I"
ZADD mySortedSet 104 "J"
ZADD mySortedSet 113 "K"
```

If I want to do pagination in reverse order, starting at an arbitrary slice, I can start with this:

```
// Returns G, F, E, as expected.
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE mySortedSet 72 (46
```

Now, knowing only that my upper bound is 46, I can get the previous 3 items in the set, D, C, and B, without knowing the lower bound by doing:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE mySortedSet 46 -inf LIMIT 0, 3
```

My question is, how can I get the next 3 items in the set, J, I and H, in that order, knowing only that the upper bound is 72?

```
// Good start, returns K, J, I, H
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE mySortedSet +inf (72

// Returns K, J, I, due to the offset of 0.  I don't know what the correct offset is because it's from the start of the range, not the end.
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE mySortedSet +inf (72 LIMIT 0, 3
```

What I think I want is a negative offset, which I don't think is supported.

```
// Would return J, I, H, but actually returns an empty set.
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE mySortedSet +inf (72 LIMIT -1, 3
```

I can fake it with a forward range, and then reversing those items, but I'm looking for a native Redis solution, if one exists.

```
// Returns H, I, J - the items I want, but reversed.
ZRANGEBYSCORE mySortedSet (72 +inf LIMIT 0, 3
```

Any ideas?

To be clear, I know there is ZRANGE and ZREVRANGE, but in this querying profile, I won't know the actual index, just the score.

Comment: There's no simple way to do it. I see three options. (1) Reverse on your client (2) reverse using LUA (3) use ZCOUNT to know the number of elements and substract from there as a replacement of negative indexes.

Comment: Hey seppo0010, thanks for your input.  Am currently doing 1, and just wanted to see if there was a better way.  Not a fan of LUA scripts for something like this, but will certainly consider the ZCOUNT approach, as the query runs inside MULTI, so it will remain atomic.

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial to get the rank for an element, and then work by indexes.  Presuming that the only inputs available to your application are the initial score bounds of 72 and 46, you can do this:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGEBYSCORE mySortedSet 72 (46
1) "G"
2) "F"
3) "E"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANK mySortedSet G
(integer) 4
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGE mySortedSet 1 3
1) "J"
2) "I"
3) "H"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

The only additional call is the O(log(N)) `ZREVRANK` call.  From there, it's a bit of client side math to get the new indexes for the range you're interested in, and `ZREVRANGE` to get the values you want.

I tested this on Redis 2.6rc5, but it should work on any version over 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a reasonable approach as well.  The only problem is that I would have to break up the request into multiple calls, or else write a LUA script to handle calculating the intermediate range.  Depending on the profile of the data, O(log(N)) where N, the cardinality of the set is large, might also be more time-consuming than simply reversing a "forward ordered range", which will have M, the count of the returned.

Comment: Yeah, depending on the size of your data, grabbing all of it and reversing it could be better; don't forget though, you end up paying network transfer costs for what you don't use.  Unfortunately, pipelining doesn't get you much here, since you need the intermediate values to build the subsequent queries. Not sure what other options you have short of redesigning things upstream to provide different inputs.