# Rest api pagination

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

I have a use case where I have an api which fetches the results from the database and I validate the request against a set of input preferences and filter the result.

I need to implement pagination for this. I cannot use mysql query pagination since I am not directly returning the result from the sql, I am processing it and then filtering the results.

Is there any way that I can fetch the entire result and store the processed result somewhere like redis or any other cache store and then paginate over that ??

Comment: you can store results even in memory; the main problem in such caching is need of synchronization data between cache and main storage (e. g. some data that should be displayed on second page, have changed between request of first and second page)

Comment: By storing in memory you mean local storage? Since the service is not hosted in a single machine and is in a cluster, we cannot do this. We need a distributed store. Currently I find this achievable only through redis or hazlecast like distributed store. Sync is always a problem but its a trade off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can fetch the entire result and store the processed result somewhere like redis or any other cache store and then paginate over that ??

Yes: as explained here: [Reverse Pagination Through A Redis Sorted Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713001/reverse-pagination-through-a-redis-sorted-set)